# server domain name cannot be accessed but ip address can

Tags: wordpress, apache, subdomain, server

I have one apache server that runs wordpress blog and I registered one domain for it. Basically, the domain works fine, the domain can be accessed directly. But I found that the sub-folder php files i cannot access directly. For example, each URL like "abc.com/wp-admin/post-new.php" is not accessible, but ip address is ok. If i access URL thur ip address like "1.2.3.4/wp-admin/post-new.php", it's fine. So I don't know where the problem is?

Another question is about facebook cannot fetch the blog content if the URL is domain. For example, if I type URL "abc.com" facebook cannot fetch the blog's content, but when I change the domain to ip address such as "1.2.3.4/", it's ok.

Could anyone give me suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where have you registered domain? DNS records take some time to propagate...

Comment: Did you define `ServerName abc.com` in your Apache server configurations ? Snippet from your `<VirtualHost>` would be helpful.